# Fourier transform in polar coordinates

Tags: fourier-transform, polar-coordinates

I have this formula that should be the Fourier transform for a generic coordinate system in the plane:

$\vec E(\vec k)=\int \vec E(\vec x) e^{-i \vec k \cdot \vec x} dx^2$

- However I don't understand on which interval should I integer?
- How should I write it for polar coordinates?

Comment: The integral is over all of the plane, i.e. $-\infty<x<\infty,\ -\infty<y<\infty.$

Comment: Yes for Cartesian coordinates, but I think this formula could be considered general

Comment: In polar coordinates, $dx^2 = r\,dr\,d\theta$ and the integration runs over $0<r<\infty,\ 0<\theta<2\pi.$